# Is there a way I can copy code from Eclipse IDE with line numbers so I can paste it into a word document?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, ide, copy-paste

I need to put my code into a word document with line numbers but when I copy it the line numbers are not copied.
I printed it to a pdf and while this gave the line numbers, I couldn't copy the formatting into the word document (lost colours when copied from pdf to word document too).
Does anyone know how I can copy code from Eclipse with line numbers without losing the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Every editor has their own language environment and word is just a text editor with no language environment in it that why you won't be able to see your code with number lines or color-coding.

If you switch to some other text editor like sublime you might be able to work more freely in it.

Comment: This is not really a proper answer because it misses the point. Wether or not Word understands code and line numbers is of no importance. The question is wether Eclipse has some copy mode that copies code in a rich text way that includes e.g. syntax highlighting, line numbers, etc.

Comment: As from my research, I didn't find anything like that but I offer the best solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options.

1. Find a site on the web that offers a text numbering service.  I actually found one but am reluctant to post the link.  I am certain there are many.  Then past your code there, renumber and recopy. This worked when I tried it.
2. Another solution (the fun one) would be to write a java program to accept pasted text and renumber for you.  You could specify this an an external editor and add any controls you like.  Or find an editor that does this.  From Eclipse you can reopen your current Eclipse editor's contents using another app.
3. And finally, there's the screen grab.

Unfortunately, I could not find an intrinsic capability in Eclipse to do this.  A possibility related to number (2) above would be an Eclipse plugin.